# Referencing multi-sheet named range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range in Excel that I am trying to clear using VBA.

The problem with the range is that spans across multiple sheets and I am not sure how to properly reference the named range in VBA since it covers multiple sheets.

The Named Range "Counts" is set to Workbook scope with the following cell references:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1, Sheet2!$A$1, Sheet3!$A$1
```

When clearing a named range where it only has cells referenced on one sheet I use the following:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Counts").ClearContents
```

---

I have tried the following but neither seemed to work.

```
ThisWorkbook.Range("Counts").ClearContents
```

and

```
Range("Counts").ClearContents
```

The last gives me a global error.

Comment: How did you define the range name across multiple sheets? Can you post the range name formula?

Comment: I have added this now to the original question

Comment: Microsoft says to do this but it also does not work

Sub ClearRange() 
    Application.Goto Reference:="MyRange" 
    Selection.ClearContents 
End Sub

Comment: How are you using the range? I cannot find anything that works with such a range, not even SUM(). So what are you doing with it?

Comment: I was just wanting it to clear the named range areas if possible without having multiple named ranges per sheet to avoid confusion but it appears this is not possible.

Comment: What is the reason that you have such a range across three sheets? Is this just a theoretical exercise? Some formulas work with 3d Ranges, like `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1)` but the range name defined with `=(Sheet1:Sheet3!$A$1)` cannot be used in any formula.

Comment: I have several workbooks that employees put the counts of items on a floor in. Every day we run some VBA to clear the counts. And the code references the named range  "Counts" when clearing them.

We just added a new floor that has 3 separate areas. So I wanted to divide each area on a separate sheet and have a named range cover across all the sheets and just reference the name to clear it instead of having a different named range for each sheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100942/discussion-between-matthew-lozoya-and-teylyn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a range that goes across multiple sheets (which does not work, as we have established), you need a worksheet scoped range in each sheet.

When defining a range name you can set its scope to workbook or the current sheet. This way you can have the same range name in many sheets.

Use VBA to loop through all worksheet, access the ws.Range("TheRangeName") on the current sheet and clear its contents.

That's a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would write something that displays the names and you can use that to remove it...

In the immediate window:

```
For i = 1 to names.count:Debug.print i, Names(i).RefersTo, Names(i).name:next
```

You can then either use th name or the index to remove the particular name you want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted what I was wanting I was wanting to clear the values from the named range not remove the name

Answer (score 0):

Rory Archibald states on his [website post about named ranges](http://excelmatters.com/referring-to-ranges-in-vba/) that: **A Range object can only refer to cells on one worksheet. You cannot refer to cells on different sheets with one Range object.**

So I am unable to accomplish what I was wanting but I should be able to just create multiple named ranges and just clear them one at a time.

I was able to complete the code for this as follows with inspiration from [teylyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447970/teylyn)

```
Public Sub ClearRanges()
'Checks if named Range exists on sheet if it does then clear contents

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Len(ws.Range("Counts").Name) <> 0 Then
            ws.Range("Counts").ClearContents
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```